# sed grouping don't catch whole group

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have a file with lines like the following:

```
TsM_000477300_transcript_id_TsM_000477300_gene_id_TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200_transcript_id_TsM_000541200_gene_id_TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400_transcript_id_TsM_000020400_gene_id_TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600_transcript_id_TsM_000268600_gene_id_TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800_transcript_id_TsM_000533800_gene_id_TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300_transcript_id_TsM_000208300_gene_id_TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500_transcript_id_TsM_000379500_gene_id_TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200_transcript_id_TsM_000882200_gene_id_TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700_transcript_id_TsM_001173700_gene_id_TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

The output I want is this one:

```
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

I've used  `sed -E 's/(^.+)_transcript_id_.+.,(.*$)/\1,\2/'`
But I can't get what I want. Here is my output:

```
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

I've tried some variations but got no success and I don't no why.

Comment: The reason is that regular expressions are greedy, so `.+.,` will match anything until _the last `,`_ encountered on the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `.+.,` greedily matches everything up to and including the *last* `,`

You could modify that to `[^,]+.,` or just `[^,]+,` to simulate non-greediness in a CSV context. However you likely can do something much simpler, for example

```
$ sed 's/_transcript_id_[^,]*//' file
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

Answer (score 4):

As already explained, the problem is that your regex looks for the longest possible match. Another solution would be to use a tool that allows for non-greedy regexes:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(TsM_.+?)_.+?,/$1,/' file
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

Or, using a slightly tweaked version of your original attempt:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(^.+)_transcript_id_.+?,(.*$)/\1,\2/' file
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

Of course, in your data, the transcript id seems to be repeated at the end, so you could simply do:

```
$ cut -d_ -f9- file
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```

Or:

```
$ sed 's/.*TsM/TsM/' file
TsM_000477300,extr 29
TsM_000541200,extr 9,plas 7,mito 6.5,cyto_mito 4,E.R. 3,lyso 3,golg 3,E.R._golg 3
TsM_000020400,extr 28,cyto 1,E.R. 1,pero 1,lyso 1,cyto_pero 1
TsM_000268600,extr 13,plas 7,E.R. 5,lyso 3,golg 2
TsM_000533800,extr 31
TsM_000208300,extr 19,pero 5,lyso 4,plas 2,E.R. 2
TsM_000379500,extr 15,golg 12,lyso 3
TsM_000882200,extr 32
TsM_001173700,extr 31
```